# Displaying member join date on page

Tags: loop, database, user-registration

I added a custom field to the user profile that asked for the date users joined my club. How can i pull this data and display on a page to celebrate anniversaries of users?

(for example: For may, this page would show all users who had originally joined in May by name and month and day)

I know I need a loop for this, just not sure how to pull in the data from the profile field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) class to query on user meta, however, your specific example of querying for a list of users with a join date matching a specific month and from *any year* requires a query more complex than what you can do out of the box with the `WP_User_Query` class.

First, it's important that the date format be correct and strictly enforced if you're going to be querying on this data. I'd suggest using a jQuery datepicker widget to enable input of dates into the join date field. YYYY-MM-DD is the standard MySQL date format.

---

### EXAMPLE 1

Here's an example of a simple query that will load all users who joined this month:

```
$first = new DateTime();
$first->modify( 'first day of this month' );
$first = $first->format( 'Y-m-d' );

$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'join_date',
    'meta_value' => $first,
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

---

### EXAMPLE 2

Here's a more complex meta query that will load users between specific dates:

```
$first = new DateTime();
$first->modify( 'first day of this month' );
$first = $first->format( 'Y-m-d' );
$last = new DateTime();
$last->modify( 'last day of this month' );
$last = $last->format('Y-m-d');

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'join_date',
            'value' => array( $first, $last ),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )

    )
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

---

### EXAMPLE 3

For custom queries, you can modify the SQL directly. The first step is to set up a simple query:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'join_date',
    'meta_value' => 0,
);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$users = $user_query->get_results();

foreach( $users as $user ):
    echo $user->user_nicename;
    echo ' joined ';
    echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'join_date', true );
endforeach;
```

Next, we add an action to `pre_user_query` to check for our simple query, and modify the SQL to just match the month and ignore year:

```
function wpse52318_user_query( $query ){
    if( $query->query_vars['meta_key'] == 'join_date' && $query->query_vars['meta_value'] === 0 ):
        global $wpdb;
        $thismonth = date('m');
        $query->query_where = "WHERE 1=1 AND ( $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'join_date' AND ( MONTH( $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value ) = $thismonth ) )";
    endif;
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse52318_user_query' );
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your help. Per your website, I had previously sent you a thank you telepathically, but you never know about how those things are received...so I wanted followed up with a post here. 

If I can ask a follow-up question, where do I need to put this in order to view the results on the page. Do I need to just create a custom template with this as the body? Thanks.

Comment: @Oliver - the query would go in whatever template you wanted to display it in. the `pre_user_query` action and associated function should go in your theme's `functions.php` file.